# How to get the type of a field in Alfresco

Tags: java, alfresco

I need to get the type of a field when I only know the name it's name. For example, for field `cm:title` I want to get `d:mltext`. How can I do that with Alfresco 5.0.d?

Thank you!

Comment: Where do you need to get this type? Client-side javascript? Share server-side javascript? Repo javascript? Repo Java? Other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
QName key = ContentModel.PROP_TITLE;       
String type = serviceRegistry.getDictionaryService().getProperty(key).getDataType().getName().getPrefixString();
```